# Having problems passing template literals in function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, template-literals, queryselector

newb here. I'm trying to pass a variable in my function but when I include it in my code (as a template literal) it doesnt work. I'm really tyring to keep the code clean by passing the customer number vs copying the code 4x times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
let customer1Svg = document.querySelector("#customer1Select");
let customer2Svg = document.querySelector("#customer2Select");
let customer3Svg = document.querySelector("#customer3Select");
let customer4Svg = document.querySelector("#customer4Select");

 function toChair(custNum) {
  
 `customer${custNum}Svg`.classList.remove(`startPositionCustomer${custNum}`);
 `customer${custNum}Svg`.classList.remove(`moveCustomer${custNum}OffScreen`);
 `customer${custNum}Svg`.classList.add(`moveCustomer${custNum}ToChair`);
 }

    toChair(1);
    toChair(2);
    toChair(3);
    toChair(4);
```

Comment: I think you are trying to use a dynamically create variable name but you can't do that. Do you have variables like `customer1Svg`? Not clear what initial strings shown should reference. Provide some sample html and the code that stores the elements in the html you are trying to modify. See [mcve]

Comment: where are you using document.querySelector?

Comment: You should have an array variable `customerSvg` and then index into it with `custNum`.

Comment: @charlietfl  Thanks I edited my example, thanks to the feedback.

Comment: @Asutosh, thanks I forgot to add that in the example, just edited my post

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, that makes sense.  Ill try to figure out a for loop that would make this work properly.

Comment: Use an object instead... `const custSvg = { 1: document.querySelector("#customer1Select")}` then in function `custSvg[custNum].classlist..`

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Will try that also.